# Need Guidance On How To Manage Game Items in Skiller Turn Based Game

Tags: android, sdk, multiplayer

Being a beginner to the Skiller platform, I'm really not sure how should I manage the game items in my turn based game. I'm essentially creating a new turn-based game using the following snippet.

```
SKTurnBasedGame game = new SKTurnBasedGame(context, listener);
game.useGameItem(itemId);
```

I'm developing a turn-based game similar to Tic-Tac-Toe. My question is how do I manage the game items in the onUseGameItemResponse() response? I specifically need to know how to handle the cases where item returns a non-zero status code.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Both in multiplayer games and single player games you can use use or award game items that were purchased by the user in your game.

By calling the useGameItem API you decrease the amount of items the user has, by one. If the status code is zero (OK) it means you successfully updated his items status on the server side. If you receive some error code it means the item was not properly updated on the server side and you should try to update it later on. From the server side this action is stateless thus you can always retry completing this operation.

If you will have any other question please write us to developers@skiller-games.com or visit our developers forum at [www.skiller-games.com](http://www.skiller-games.com)

Good luck